# YouTube IFrame Player API - function calls

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

By copying the code from the official API Reference, I have a created a working version of the IFrame on a local web server (localhost). I am able to manipulate the embedded video controls and make things like simple play/ pause/ stop buttons.

However, I am stuck on the API functions reference. For instance, I would like to implement

```
loadVideoById("bHQqvYy5KYo", 5, "large")
```

in my code. When I look at the reference Samples, I recognize the `loadVideoById` function being used there. When I use the Inspector to find out how the function is explicitly implemented in the sample, I get lost in the API structure.

I have tried calling like this

```
function testLoad() {
  player.loadVideoById("bHQqvYy5KYo", 5, "large");
}
```

from a simple button onclick, that does not function.

Could you please give me an explicit example on how to call the `loadVideoById` function?

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working like this:

```
function loadVideoById() {
  player.loadVideoById("xx6I0GrKlQQ", 5, "large");
}
```

The function had to be named `loadVideoById` for some reason unclear to me. Would be nice if someone explained the basics I obviously missed :)